# Pandas looking for oscillations in dataset

Tags: pandas

I am fairly new to pandas and I am looking at some flight data. I have some flight paths that seem to oscillate as seen below:

[image]

And others that look fairly normal in their altitude

[image]

I'd like to be able to identify any flights in my dataset that have oscillations (is that the right word?) like the first graph where it appears the pilot is periodically gaining and dropping altitude. Then I can look at other factors that might have been causing this.

I thought maybe some mixture of standard deviation and mean would help me identify this, but I must admit I am not very mathematically inclined (yet! working on it). There doesn't seem to be a correlation at least when looking just at these 2 samples.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please share the data related to your charts to be reproducible.

Comment: @Corralien I'd imagine this is a mathematical concept irrelevant of the data itself. I'd assume the same principles could be applied to a sine wave vs a straight line. The full dataset is here: https://kilthub.cmu.edu/articles/dataset/TrajAir_A_General_Aviation_Trajectory_Dataset/14866251 , but it's quite large.

Comment: So maybe you should ask to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For what it's worth, if you have a temporal signal, try to use the [FFT](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html)